# UITableView bug

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

guys. I have table view controller and modal view. Sometimes after closing modal view, my table view isn't scrolling. May be you know, where is problem?
PS: My modal view is very "heavy", but it shouldn't cause problems.

Comment: what u mean not scroling? halts?

Comment: Are you using gesture recognizers? Are you using scrollviews in conjunction with tableviews? Is the app working other than not scrolling?

Comment: I can not move up or down cells

Comment: Robert, it's uitableview with swipeable cells (uiswipegesturerecognizer). I can tap button in uinavigationcontroller for example or make swipe on cell, but can't move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen behaviour similar to this. I bet your table view controller is being unloaded due to a memory warning when your modal is visible (you mention that the modal is "heavy" - I assume you mean heavy in terms of memory footprint). Then it is re-loaded when you dismiss the modal. I have quite often seen table views not able to scroll when they are initially loaded.

I think that a workaround I have used in the past is to alter the table view's frame height to be bigger then back again to the right size in `viewWillAppear:`. I suggest you try something like that.

In the meantime - I think you should try to nail down a simple sample project that shows the issue and [file it as a radar](http://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: I think, that you are right, but I can't change size of table view (i've tried to change frame, but it isn't working), may be we have other way?

Comment: I'm just writing a sample project to see if I can figure out another way to get around it & if it's even the problem in the first place (I am pretty sure it is though).

Comment: Hmm yeh I can't replicate it right now. I have seen it before though as well. Perhaps try adding a `setContentOffset:` on the table view in `viewWillAppear:`? It's ugly, but may work.

Comment: Changing contentSize in viewWillAppear fixed problem. Thank you!

Comment: Great stuff. I urge you to try and create a cut down project that shows the problem and file it as a bug :-).